# ng-grid group header row templating

Tags: angularjs, templates, ng-grid

I am using ng-grid and I need to add 2 clickable images in each group level header row (I need this so I can set all unanswered checkboxes in a particular group to on or off).

I have been looking for a day or so and have tried different things but I can only find things that alter the top level grid header, not by individual group headers.  I only want the images to affect a particular group so really need the images in the group level header.

Comment: Do you need a way to alter the aggregated row template?

Comment: That is exactly it - thanks Alex!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to do this with aggregateTemplate:

var htmlAggregateTemplate = "DEFINE HTML FOR HEADER";

then used in the scope grid variables:

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
    aggregateTemplate: htmlAggregateTemplate
};
```